# Ember app "ghosting" across routes

Tags: ember.js

So this is strange. Does anyone know how to stop an Ember app from "ghosting" when you change routes? By this I mean... Let's take an example. If I go to route "A" that has a dropdown and a label in its template, and then I go to route "B", some elements of template A are appended to template B's render. This keeps happening across apps. Anyone know how to stop it? Much appreciated!

Comment: Check your html it's often due to mising closin tabs

Comment: Yeah? Will double check that.. Thanks!

Comment: Nope - that did not help. I've tripled checked.

Comment: Could you possibly reproduce on a jsbin ?